# Jenkins doesn't trigger job on gerrit event

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I cant figure out how to setup gerrit trigger plugin.

Manual build start builds current repo correctly. Test gerrit plugin connection is "Success".

Gerrit is configured according to plugin description article: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger

Jenkins is 1.635; Gerrit trigger is 2.17.2. Gerrit is v2.11.3

Also tried "Type: plain. Pattern: project1, branches: */base/**" gerrit project settings. didnt work.

Gerrit trigger plugin global config:
[image: Gerrit trigger global config]

Gerrit trigger plugin global config expanded (it has serveradmin user on the picture but i tried user created for jenkins as well):

[image]

Job settings:

[image: job settings]

Probably I'm missing something. Is there a way to figure out what's wrong? Maybe some console commands to figure out if gerrit jenkins user can reach the stream & plugin log?

Comment: Has the Jenkins user the *Stream Events* permission in Gerrit?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to update Gerrit to the last version and give the good "Access Right" to your Jenkins user.

Follow [this set up](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger#GerritTrigger-Gerritaccessrights)